# Illustrator placed item via applescript produces layer groups?

Tags: applescript

Illustrator placed item on new layer via applescript (simple shape)
results in the placed being grouped multiple times within the layer.

I could'nt find any answers in the dictionary or forums, so I wonder if any of you has come across this before and found a solution to keep the imported path top level on the new Illustrator layer.

Thanks a lot !

[screenshot layers original path file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtP3G.gif)

[screenshot after embed via applescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bg86.gif)
Applescript:

```
tell myDoc
            set layer_cmyk to current layer
            set name of current layer to "cmyk"
            set myLayer to make new layer with properties {name:"diecut"}
            set placed_file to make new placed item ¬
                with properties {file path:("the_shape_to_embed.ai")}
            embed placed_file without dialogs
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was no way to avoid the additional grouping through clipping paths of vector artwork imported via "placed item".

Solved the issue by having Applescript open the vector art to import, copy the layer contents in question to the clipboard and paste it to the other Illustrator file - into a chosen layer.

Works like a charm.